# Getting data from Parse with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock that returns [AnyObject]? how do I extract the column data?

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your results like so:
objects as? [PFObject], then each result will contain a PFObject dictionary with the column name as the key. for example o["id"] will return the value of the id column for a specific object

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
let data = objects as! [PFObject]
let firstObject = objects[0]
// firstObject["Column"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is easy like the code below,

In my case i get the score you can use your DB table column names

```
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                           var score : Int? = object["score"] as! Int?

                    }
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                }
            }
```